Real time IPFS data of created token
I’m looking for any faster way to get IPFS data that will take maximum like maximum 200ms and the lower the better.
My code is written in Rust and currently I’m just calling some providers and waiting for the first one to return the data and sometimes it takes even more than 1s while every millisecond is important because I’m buying newly created pools (I can’t make the data fetching before the pool, only after the creation as of pump.fun)
Will be glad for an assistance,
Thanks.

Could you explain the nature of the data?

What is the data of?
What is the size of the data?
Which pinning gateways are available for this data? - ie. Pinata
Which IPFS libraries are being used for managing downloads?

